# Model override doesn't work

Tags: overrides, model

I need to override Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection, but the rewrite doesn't work...
This is the config.xml file of MY MODULE:

```
<config>
 <modules>
    <MY_MODULE>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MY_MODULE>
 </modules>
 <global> 
.......
   <models>
     <catalog_resource_product>
       <rewrite>      
         <collection>MY_MODULE_Model_MODELNAME</collection>              
       </rewrite> 
     </catalog_resource_product> 
   </models>
.......    
 </global>
</config>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<models>
 <catalog_resource>
   <rewrite>      
     <product_collection>MY_MODULE_Model_MODELNAME</product_collection>              
   </rewrite> 
 </catalog_resource> 
</models>
```

The xml section above should do the trick.